# How can I put my YouTube videos on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put both my YouTube videos on the same line. I tried adjusting the iframe and creating a wrapper, but it doesn't seem like I'm targeting the right things. I'm not sure where I went wrong. Here's my JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6a73m27n/

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

iframe {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="video_wrapper">
  <iframe width="400" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3S_dmC2soik" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="400" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bdGhmMzj4uE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by "line". Do you want them to stack on top of one another?

Comment: Your code works, just make sure that they both *fit* on the same line. You'll need at least 800px of width to your wrapper to accomplish this.

Comment: In case you want two videos next to eachother (and exactly two) you have to put `width: 50%` for the `iframe`

Comment: Okay, thank you. And I meant next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Just mention the width of the video in percentage as shown below:

```html
<div class="video_wrapper">

<iframe width="40%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3S_dmC2soik" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="40%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bdGhmMzj4uE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually works if you have enough width for both of them on one line.
Despite that, I would recommend you to put this styling to the iframe instead:

```
iframe {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /* or middle, bottom, baseline by your preference */
}
```